# X (?) restarting every minute on debian testing

Tags: debian, xorg, startup

I upgraded debian (testing) last night and I'm stuck with this annoying bug, in which every minute or so it sends me back to the login screen.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949111/debian-login-loop, from that screen I switched to the terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> and then typed `startx` which allows me to keep some active session, but the login screen still pops up and then I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> to switch into the active session. I also took the advice from that ask and used:

```
sudo find ~/ -user root -exec chown username:username {} \;
```

(with my own username) on my home directory, but it hasn't worked. Neither has:

```
chown user.user ./.Xauthority
```

I've also taken a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, however the only errors/warnings in both were

```
[  3068.878] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[  3069.290] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[  3173.113] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  3173.180] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  3173.181] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
```

Full logs are here:

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old](https://u.teknik.io/KEVzr.old)

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://u.teknik.io/6BlEm.log)

My question is, how do I stop this behavior from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the issue. I was still running SLiM and it was all kinds of incompatible with the updated OS. Installed lightdm, set it to my default and the problem seemed to stop.